# Best Practices - sequence execution of commands in ObjC

Tags: ios, objective-c

What's the best way to execute a series of commands in a certain order? I keep getting frustrated by the darn concurrency of execution in ObjC. This is one of these cases where I realize that I'm a designer, not a "real" coder.

I'm experimenting with SpriteKit on iOS, and I want a sequence of things to occur when an energy gauge reaches <=0.

1. Call a method to create an explosion at the final contact. The method takes arguments about position and size of explosion.
2. Call another method afterwards that calls up a new scene, a results screen.

My problem occurs when the new scene gets called **before** I get a chance to see the last explosion.

Here's the relevant code:

```
- (void) doGameOver
{
    damageIndicator.progress = 0;
    energyLeft.text = @"Energy:0%";
    GameOver *newScene = [[GameOver alloc]initWithSize:self.size];
    newScene.timeElapsed = [started timeIntervalSinceNow];
    [self.view presentScene:newScene transition:[SKTransition fadeWithColor:[SKColor whiteColor] duration:1]];
[damageIndicator removeFromSuperview];
```

}

```
- (void) makeExplosionWithSize:(float)myBoomSize inPosition:(CGPoint)boomPosition
{
NSString *myFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"explosion" ofType:@"sks"];
SKEmitterNode *boom = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:myFile];
boom.position = boomPosition;
boom.particleSize = CGSizeMake(myBoomSize, myBoomSize);
[self addChild:boom];
[self runAction:self.playMySound];
```

}

```
- (void)adjustScoreWithDamage:(float)hitDamage atPosition:(CGPoint)pos
{
_damage = _damage -(hitDamage);
if (_damage < 0) {
//these are the two things I need to execute sequentially
    [self makeExplosionWithSize:500 inPosition:pos];
    [self doGameOver]
}
```

}

I've tried schemes using bools (gameOver = YES), but think I may need to create a completion handler, which just makes my head spin.

Can anyone suggest the **easiest** way to accomplish this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest (not best) probably would be to replace

```
[self doGameOver];
```

with

```
[self performSelector:@selector(doGameOver) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to try that. What would be the best answer?

Comment: You should definitely dig into blocks: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html

Comment: I am not too familiar with SpriteKit but you can use: 
- (void)runAction:(SKAction *)action completion:(void (^)(void))block 
and trigger your game over action in the completion block.

Comment: Yes, but only if the first action is a SKAction, not a method. Wish there was a -(void)runMethod:(id)myMethod completion: ... way of firing off sequential methods.

Comment: Jacob: probably should, but the syntax is so convoluted... I can't seem to visually parse it easily. I've read over the apple docs, but it hasn't clicked, for me. The easy solution worked well for what I needed in this instance. Maybe I'll grasp blocks eventually.

Comment: If you are looking for the best practice then blocks are definitely the way to go. I had a quick look at spritekit and you can also run a sequence like so:

[boom runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction waitForDuration:2.0],[SKAction removeFromParent]]]
completion:^{
           
}];

Comment: Yeah, like I said above, that works with SKActions, but not methods. I had 2 methods I needed to fire off sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

I may misunderstand what you're going for, but it sounds like what should happen is:

1. The explosion begins.
2. There's a pause of [n] seconds.
3. The Game Over screen is presented.

To accomplish that, you might want to just fire "doGameOver" with an NSTimer rather than worry about having it fire immediately after the explosion completes.

Here's an example with a 3 second delay:

```
NSTimer *gameOverTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(doGameOver:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:gameOverTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Comment: Great answer. Will try out soonest.

Comment: Jacob K's more concise answer is functionally identical, so unless you need the control over what thread doGameOver runs in, you might as well use that!